# mysql increase value when button is clicked

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I can't seem to find a way to increase a value stored in a mysql database when a button is clicked.

The button in html (*not including styling with css*):

```
<a class="button">Press Me</a>
```

I've my mysql database all set up and working and I just can't find a way to increase a value in the database everytime this button/link is clicked. You should be able to click this button multiple times without leaving the page.

I've tried using PHP but it will only send the information once the page is loaded which means the button hasn't been clicked, and also I haven't found a way to increase the value on every click.. By the way, this doesn't have to be done with PHP.

```
<?php
// Connection to database
  $connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
// Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

// Increasing the current value with 1
  mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE articles SET amount = (amount + 1)
      WHERE id='1'");

  mysqli_close($connection);

  echo "PHP RAN successfully";     ?>
```

**Also, sorry for my bad English, i'm an Swedish dude :)*

Comment: Use AJAX and connect the 'onclick' event from your button to your .php that way.

Comment: If you wish to do that, you'll need to combine a server language (ex:PhP) with some piece of client-code (Javascript) to do an AJAX request to you PhP without trigerring a whole page reload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include jquery in your page as JS library.

```
<a class="button" id="press_me">Press Me</a>
<script>
    $(function (){
            $('#press_me').click(function(){
            var request = $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: "server_code_increment.php"                               
                                  });
                                  request.done(function( msg ) {

                                        alert('Success');
                                        return;

                                  });
                                  request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                                        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
                                    });
            });
    });
    </script>
```

server_code_increment.php

```
<?php
// Connection to database
  $connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
// Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo 'NOT_OK';
    //echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

// Increasing the current value with 1
  mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE articles SET amount = (amount + 1)
      WHERE id='1'");

  mysqli_close($connection);

  echo 'OK';   ?>
```

Modify as per your need

Answer (score 0):

you don't HAVE to use ajax though its probably the prettier way.  this will work with a basic ahref reload page

```
<a class="button" href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>&a=increase">Press Me</a>

<?php
if ($_GET['a']=="increase") {
// Connection to database
  $connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
// Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

// Increasing the current value with 1
  mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE articles SET amount = (amount + 1)
      WHERE id='1'");

  mysqli_close($connection);

  echo "PHP RAN successfully";     
}

//echo out the DB value here
echo $db->amount;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <a href="yourpage.php?id=1">Press me</a>
```

id (its only avariable)

```
<? php
 $no=$_get['id'];
?>
```

Select your last inserted amount from db

```
 eg: $lastamount=mysql_query("select query for last insertdata");
 write 
 $no=$lastamount+$no;
 mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE articles SET amount = $no
  WHERE id='1'");
```